# Tfssecurity - Set Permission for Release and Deployment Groups

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

at the moment i´m writing a script for setting TFS-Permissions with Tfssecurity.exe.
I solved the stuff for about all areas in TFS, but now i´m getting stuck with "Release" and "Deployment Group" permissions.
For "Release" i found in the securitynamesspace Json a Namespace called "ReleaseManagement" - if i do a tfssecurity /a i can´t find that namespace.
If i try to set permission with tfssecurity.exe /a+ Release Management it also tells me that there is not Workspace with that name, also if i write it without space between (ReleaseManagement).
Also i can´t find anything for Deployment Groups.

So i hope to get a hint from you guys for these two permission areas (namespaces).
==> System: VSTS

Here are the namespaces i´m getting with /a:
Hey, thx for your answer. My problem is that on VSTS i don´t get this namespace back with /a => I´m getting all namespaces, but this one is missing and also tells me it can´t find it. The only way i got it back is in the json i get from https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?api-version=4.1.
Here are the namespaces i´m getting with /a:

```
 WorkItemTrackingAdministration
 DistributedTask
 WorkItemQueryFolders
 Git Repositories
 VersionControlItems2
 EventSubscriber
 WorkItemTrackingProvision
 ServiceEndpoints
 ServiceHooks
 Chat
 Collection
 Proxy
 Plan
 Process
 AccountAdminSecurity
 Library
 Project
 EventSubscription
 CSS
 TeamLabSecurity
 ProjectAnalysisLanguageMetrics
 Tagging
 MetaTask
 Iteration
 Favorites
 Registry
 Graph
 ViewActivityPaneSecurity
 Job
 WorkItemTracking
 StrongBox
 Server
 TestManagement
 SettingEntries
 BuildAdministration
 Location
 UtilizationPermissions
 WorkItemsHub
 WebPlatform
 VersionControlPrivileges
 Workspaces
 CrossProjectWidgetView
 WorkItemTrackingConfiguration
 Discussion Threads
 DataProvider
 Social
 Security
 IdentityPicker
 ServicingOrchestration
 Build
 DashboardsPrivileges
 VersionControlItems
 Identity
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace that contains the group to which you want to add permissions for a user or group. You can also use the `tfssecurity /a` command to view a list of namespaces at the server, collection, and project level.

```
tfssecurity /a /server:ServerURL
```

You could first use above command to check if there are corresponding namespace as your need. For the name contain a space in the middle, you should use `""` for the name and enter space in the `""` such as `"Release Management"`

More details please refer this official tutorial-- [Change groups and permissions with TFSSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd)

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. My problem is that on VSTS i don´t get this namespace back with /a => I´m getting all namespaces, but this one is missing and also tells me it can´t find it. The only way i got it back is in the json i get from https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com/_apis/securitynamespaces/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?api-version=4.1.

Comment: @Chrizzo Could you set permissions  for Release and Deployment Groups in web portal? If you directly enter `"Release Management"` when using tfssecurity  command, what's the result or error message do you get?

Comment: Here is what i get back, sorry it is in german...
tfssecurity
Microsoft (R) TFSSecurity - Team Foundation Server-Sicherheitstool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Der Team Foundation-Zielserver ist https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/.

Der Sicherheitsnamespace "Release Management" ist nicht vorhanden. **(Securitynamespace "Release Management" is not available")**
Für die folgenden Sicherheitsnamespaces können Berechtigungen festgelegt werden:
     WorkItemTrackingAdministration
     DistributedTask

Comment: @Chrizzo If so, afraid you could not use tfssecurity  command to Set Permission for Release and Deployment Groups.

Comment: Hi Patrick, no update on this! Also wrote a thread in MS-Forums -> Waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0):

realise this is long gone but you get back different namespaces when you use the /collection: rather than the /server: parameter.
So when you don't see the namespaces the same as REST api, that's why. 
Hopefully helpful for anyone who ambles by.

I just got caught with this.